# c DES and C# DES issue

Tags: c#, c, cryptography, openssl

I have looked for this across the whole of the web, but cannot find a definitive answer:

I have some C# code that uses the DESCryptoServiceProvider (Mode = CRC, Padding = none) and I am using the openssl library to do the same using C.

So far in C#

```
public static byte[] DESEncrypt(byte[] Source, byte[] Key)
    {
        byte[] DESKey = new byte[8];
        Array.Copy(Key, 0, DESKey, 0, 8);

        DisplayByteArray("DESKey", DESKey);

        System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        DES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;
        byte[] IV = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        DES.IV = IV;
        DES.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None;
        DES.Key = DESKey;

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cs = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(ms, DES.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cs.Write(Source, 0, Source.Length);

        byte[] outdata = ms.ToArray();

        cs.Close();
        ms.Close();

        return outdata;
    }
```

and in C

```
int DesEncrypt(BYTE *pOriginal, BYTE *oEncrypted, int nDataLength, BYTE *pKey)
{
  DES_cblock ivec = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
  DES_cblock key[8];
  memcpy(key,&pKey[0], 8);
  memset(oEncrypted, 0, sizeof(oEncrypted));
  printf("\nDESkey: ");DisplayByteArray((BYTE *)&key[0], 8);
  DES_key_schedule ks;
  memcpy((DES_cblock *)key, &ks, 8);
  if (DES_set_key_checked((DES_cblock *)key, &ks))
    printf("\nChecked OKAY");
  else
    printf("\nCheck FAILED");
  DES_cbc_encrypt(pOriginal, oEncrypted, nDataLength, &ks, &ivec, DES_ENCRYPT);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Are you aware that DES is not secure? Its key is far too small.

Comment: Also, using a static IV can leak information about the plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following line

```
DES_cblock key[8];
```

should be

```
DES_cblock key;
```

Since, you are using single key.

One big problem is in

```
memcpy((DES_cblock *)key, &ks, 8);
if (DES_set_key_checked((DES_cblock *)key, &ks))
    printf("\nChecked OKAY");
else
    printf("\nCheck FAILED");
```

Do not memcpy `key` by `ks`. Your `ks` is uninitialized.
`DES_set_key_checked` sets key schedule from the key.

memcpy should not be there before DES_set_key_checked.

It should be

```
if (DES_set_key_checked((DES_cblock *)key, &ks))
    printf("\nChecked OKAY");
else
    printf("\nCheck FAILED");
```

Do not typecast unless you are sure why you are doing. Explicit typecast can hide many errors.

Comment: In win I get the following:DESKey
02 04 06 07 01 0A E1 FD
.  .  .  .  .  .  ?  ?
8 bytes  :
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
encrypted:
B9 9E 23 4F 0A BF 45 A7
?  ?  #  O  .  ?  E  ?

Comment: Forget the last comment. It was the mistake in the C!